# bugged repaint method draws part of frame

Tags: java, repaint

I am trying to draw a figure by constructing it out of single lines. This has worked for me for a while, but after adding a few textfields and a button to control some parameters it started beeing crazy and drawing the area around the button on the area of my figure. I tried scanning the code for the source, and it seems its BETWEEN the Repaint() method and the actual content of the method, as the bug continues to occur even when I empty the method drawComponent(), but doesnt occur whenever I remove the call of repaint(). When triggering repaint it first draws the button and a small area around it on the frame(overlapping some text fields), and then draws the actual figure on that area. The full code snippets are listed below:

base class for angles:

```
package customUtilitys;

public class Angle {
    private double xRot,yRot,zRot;
    public Angle(){}
    public Angle(double x,double y,double z){
        xRot = x;
        yRot = y;
        zRot = z;
        }
    public Angle(Angle ang){
        setAngle(ang);}
    public void setAngle(double x,double y, double z){
        while(x >= 360){
            x = x - 360;
        }
        while(y >= 360){
            y = y - 360;
        }
        while(z >= 360){
            z = z - 360;
        }
        xRot = x;
        yRot = y;
        zRot = z;
    }
    public void setAngle(Angle ang){
        xRot = ang.getXAngle();
        xRot = ang.getYAngle();
        zRot = ang.getZAngle();
    }
    public double getXAngle(){
        return xRot;
    }
    public double getYAngle(){
        return yRot;
    }
    public double getZAngle(){
        return zRot;
    }
}
```

base class for 3D points:

```
package customUtilitys;

import java.awt.Point;

public class Point3D extends Point {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1242102585768332716L;
    public int x,y,z;
    public Point3D(){};
    public Point3D(double x,double y,double z){
        setLocation(x,y,z);
    }
    public Point3D(int x, int y,int z){
        setLocation(x,y,z);
    }
    public void setLocation(int x,int y,int z){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
    public void setLocation(double x,double y,double z){
        this.x = (int)Math.round(x);
        this.y = (int)Math.round(y);
        this.z = (int)Math.round(z);
    }
    public Point3D add(Point3D P){
        return new Point3D(x+P.x,y+P.y,z+P.z);
    }
    public Point3D rotate(Angle A){
        double xA = A.getXAngle();
        double yA = A.getYAngle();
        double zA = A.getZAngle();
        Matrix TransformationMatrixX = new Matrix(new double[][]{{1,0,0},{0,Math.cos(xA),-Math.sin(xA)},{0,Math.sin(xA),Math.cos(xA)}});
        Matrix TransformationMatrixY = new Matrix(new double[][]{{Math.cos(yA),0,-Math.sin(yA)},{0,1,0},{Math.sin(yA),0,Math.cos(yA)}});
        Matrix TransformationMatrixZ = new Matrix(new double[][]{{Math.cos(zA),-Math.sin(zA),0},{Math.sin(zA),Math.cos(zA),0},{0,0,1}});
        Matrix Pos = new Matrix(new double[][]{{x,y,z}});
        Pos = Pos.times(TransformationMatrixX);
        Pos = Pos.times(TransformationMatrixY);
        Pos = Pos.times(TransformationMatrixZ);
        Point3D P = new Point3D(Pos.getData()[0][0],Pos.getData()[0][1],Pos.getData()[0][2]);
        return P;
    }
    public Point transform(){
        int x2D = (int)Math.round(x/(z+4));
        int y2D = (int)Math.round(y/(z+4));
        Point P = new Point(x2D,y2D);
        return P;
    }
}
```

Importand Code:

code of the figure(unfinished Cube) that gets drawn:

```
package customUtilitys;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Cuboid extends JPanel {
    Angle angle = new Angle();
    public Point3D A=new Point3D(),B=new Point3D(),C=new Point3D(),D=newPoint3D(),E=new Point3D(),F=new Point3D(),G=new Point3D(),H=new Point3D();
    public Point3D center = new Point3D(8,8,8);
    public Cuboid(){}
    public void setCorners(Point3D A,Point3D B,Point3D C,Point3D D,Point3D E,Point3D F,Point3D G,Point3D H){
        this.A=A;
        this.B=B;
        this.C=C;
        this.D=D;
        this.E=E;
        this.F=F;
        this.G=G;
        this.H=H;
    }
    public void setCenter(Point3D P){
        center = P;
    }
    public void setAngle(double X,double Y, double Z) {
        angle.setAngle(X,Y,Z);
    }

   //The paint method of the Cube. Possible source of the problem

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Point a2 = center.add(A.rotate(angle)).transform();
        Point b2 = center.add(B.rotate(angle)).transform();
        Point c2 = center.add(C.rotate(angle)).transform();
        Point d2 = center.add(D.rotate(angle)).transform();
        Point e2 = center.add(E.rotate(angle)).transform();
        Point f2 = center.add(F.rotate(angle)).transform();
        Point g2 = center.add(G.rotate(angle)).transform();
        Point h2 = center.add(H.rotate(angle)).transform();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(a2.x*10,a2.y*10,b2.x*10,b2.y*10);
        g.drawLine(b2.x*10,b2.y*10,c2.x*10,c2.y*10);
        g.drawLine(c2.x*10,c2.y*10,d2.x*10,d2.y*10);
        g.drawLine(d2.x*10,d2.y*10,a2.x*10,a2.y*10);
        g.drawLine(e2.x*10,e2.y*10,f2.x*10,f2.y*10);
        g.drawLine(f2.x*10,f2.y*10,g2.x*10,g2.y*10);
        g.drawLine(g2.x*10,g2.y*10,h2.x*10,h2.y*10);
        g.drawLine(h2.x*10,h2.y*10,e2.x*10,e2.y*10);
        g.drawLine(a2.x*10,a2.y*10,e2.x*10,e2.y*10);
        g.drawLine(b2.x*10,b2.y*10,f2.x*10,f2.y*10);
        g.drawLine(c2.x*10,c2.y*10,g2.x*10,g2.y*10);
        g.drawLine(d2.x*10,d2.y*10,h2.x*10,h2.y*10);
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
package customUtilitys;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class UtilityTest extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UtilityTest frame = new UtilityTest();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public UtilityTest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 354);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(5, 5, 424, 310);
        contentPane.add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);  

        //{...Shortened Code...}

    //Definition of the Cube object and following repaint call. Hightest chance of problem here

        final Cuboid Cube = new Cuboid();
        panel.add(Cube);
        Cube.setBounds(50,50,160,160);
        Cube.invalidate();
        Cube.repaint();

        JButton btnDraw = new JButton("Draw");
        btnDraw.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            //{...Shortened Code...}
                Cube.invalidate();
                Cube.repaint();
            }
        });
        btnDraw.setBounds(240, 241, 80, 23);
        panel.add(btnDraw);
    }
}
```

Comment: holy crap! That's a lot of code! could you maybe give us a little less code? try to pinpoint where there might be problems and it makes our jobs way easier! [Here's some help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: LayoutManagers are also helpful, you could have saved yourself a lot of work I think.

Comment: I know it's a lot. I actually just wanted to show the last 2 code boxes, but added the first 2 so all the custom methods etc. are clear. The source of the problem lies in the last 2 boxes, which contain the drawn figure's code and the drawing method.

Comment: I removed some unneccessary code and marked some importand positions with comments.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `cube.invalidate()` which invalidates the component

> public void invalidate()
>
> Invalidates the container.
>   If the LayoutManager installed on this container is an instance of the LayoutManager2 interface, then the LayoutManager2.invalidateLayout(Container) method is invoked on it supplying this Container as the argument.
>   Afterwards this method marks this container invalid, and invalidates its ancestors.

You have to call `revalidate()`

```
 Cube.revalidate();//not invalidate()
```

Comment: I tried these changes, but the problem still occurs. My guess is that it's something with the call of the repaint method or similar.